# Вывод топ 10 в каждой категории

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, postgresql

У товаров есть категории. Покажите самых дорогих 10 товаров в каждой категории. 
Таблица catalog с полями (id,name,id_categoria,price)
Подскажите пожалуйста с запросом. Я написал на PostgreSQL. Работает он не совсем корректно...

`SELECT a.*
FROM catalog AS a
WHERE a.id IN (
  SELECT b.id
  FROM catalog AS b
  WHERE b.id_categoria  = a.id_categoria 
  ORDER BY b.id DESC, b.price DESC
  LIMIT 10
)
ORDER BY a.id_categoria , a.price DESC;`